# Get Object Type into Group in Outliner Maya

Tags: python, maya

I try to get all object type for each element into the group in Outliner.

This is my code.

```
from maya import cmds

objects = cmds.ls(selection=True, dag=True)

objects.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

# Now we loop through all the objects we have
for obj in objects:
    # We get the shortname again by splitting at the last |
    shortName = obj.split('|')[-1]

    children = cmds.listRelatives(obj, children=True) or []

    if len(children) > 0:
        for current in children:
            objType = cmds.objectType(current)
            print(objType)
```

I got this error:

> Error: RuntimeError: file /Users/jhgonzalez/Library/Preferences/Autodesk/maya/2018/scripts/AssigMaterialForEachMesh.py line 26: No object matches name: SafetyHandle_019_allFromGun:pCylinderShape21
>   Object 'SafetyHandle_019_allFromGun:pCylinderShape21' not found.

And I'm testing this code with this

[image]

Comment: Your code isn't producing any errors for me. Is this the full script?

Comment: Yeah... But I know what is the problem... The problem is that they are repeated some mesh in this scene. I fixed these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't using long names, so the script will crash if there are objects with duplicate names as Maya doesn't know how to resolve it.

For example, let's say you have a hierarchy of 3 nodes:

```
|a
  |b
    |c
```

And another hierarchy with 2 nodes:

```
|d
  |a
```

Since you're using short names, when you try to query `objectType` from `a`, it doesn't know from what hierarchy you want it from, thus just use long names:

```
from maya import cmds

objects = cmds.ls(selection=True, dag=True, l=True) # Use long parameter.

objects.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

# Now we loop through all the objects we have
for obj in objects:
    children = cmds.listRelatives(obj, f=True, children=True) or [] # Use full parameter.

    if len(children) > 0:
        for current in children:
            objType = cmds.objectType(current)
            print(objType)
```

Now it continues to work as expected, despite having duplicate names in your scene.